# Why is there no DOI and URL in the bibligraphy when using the bibliography style "acm"?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, doi

I'm using BibTex with the bibliography style "acm":

```
\begin{document}
...

\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{bibfile}
    
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the resulting pdf does not have the DOI and/or URL in the bibligraphy although they are included in the bibfile. What could I change such that the DOI appears?

Thanks a lot four your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: `acm.bst` is a BibTeX style that was last significantly changed in the late 1980s, it neither knows a `doi` nor a `url` field. If you want a more modern ACM style, you may want to try `acmart`'s `ACM-Reference-Format.bst` (https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/acmart).

Comment: If you are not married to ACM style, you could use `natbib` and one of its 'standard' styles (e.g. `plainnat`). The standard `natbib` styles also know about `doi` and `url`. Generally speaking, more modern styles often support `doi` and `url`, while older styles don't and need workarounds with `howpublished` or `note`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ask why the `doi` and `url` fields don't show up in the formatted bibliographic entries when you use the `acm` bibliography style.

The direct answer is, "because the `acm` bib style is programmed to recognize and process just the following field types (listed alphabetically): address, author, booktitle, chapter, edition, editor, howpublished, institution, journal, key, month, note, number, organization, pages, publisher, school, series, title, type, volume, and year". Any and all fields names not on this list get ignored.

You might be tempted to ask, "why wasn't the `acm` bib style programmed to recognize some other fields, such as `doi` and `url`? The answer is surprisingly simple: because the `acm` style has been around virtually unchanged since 1988, when most people (including, evidently, Oren Patashnik, the creator of BiBTeX and quite a few bib styles) had never heard of dois and URLs.